# Python Tkinter TopLevel : too many window

Tags: python, tkinter, window, toplevel

in my code i use 1 time the function to load window 2 when i click on a buttun but when i do it launch 2 window instead of 1 and only 1 has the color that i want

```
from tkinter import * 


def load_window1():
    yt_buttun.pack(side=LEFT)
    class_buttun.pack(side=LEFT)
    music_buttun.pack(side=RIGHT)
    label_tittle.pack()
    buttun_frame.pack()
    print("fenetre 1 / page d'acceuil affiché")
    window1.mainloop()


def load_window2():
    # fenetre choisir classe

    window2 = Toplevel()
    window2.config(background="#D13C3C")
    # Composants --> deuxieme page

    label_tittle2 = Label(window2, text="choisi ton programme de révision", font=("Courrier", 40), bg="#41B77F", fg='white')
    buttun_frame2 = Frame(window2, bg='#41B77F', bd=2, relief=SUNKEN)
    buttun5m = Button(buttun_frame2, text="5eme", font=("Courrier", 60), bg="#D13C3C", fg='#41B77F',command=open_HighKhala_channel)
    buttun4m = Button(buttun_frame2, text="4eme", font=("Courrier", 60), bg="#359AF1", fg='white', command=do_music)
    buttun3m = Button(buttun_frame2, text="3eme", font=("Courrier", 60), bg="#9962D8", fg='black', command=do_music)

    label_tittle2.pack()
    buttun_frame2.pack()
    buttun5m.pack()
    buttun4m.pack()
    buttun3m.pack()
    print("fenetre 2 / page choisir classe affiché")

def destroy_window1():
    window1.destroy()
    load_window2()


# fenetre acceuil

window1 = Tk()
window1.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
window1.bind('<Escape>', lambda e: window1.destroy())
window1.config(background='#41B77F')

# Composants --> première page

label_tittle = Label(window1, text="Appli d'Erkan pour le BREVET", font=("Courrier", 40), bg="#41B77F", fg='white')
buttun_frame = Frame(window1, bg='#41B77F', bd=2, relief=SUNKEN)
yt_buttun = Button(buttun_frame, text="Ma Chaine YT", font=("Courrier", 40), bg="#D13C3C", fg='#41B77F', command=open_HighKhala_channel)
class_buttun = Button(buttun_frame, text="Choisir sa classe", font=("Courrier", 40), bg="#359AF1", fg='white', command=destroy_window1)
music_buttun = Button(buttun_frame, text="Un peu de musique", font=("Courrier", 40), bg="#9962D8", fg='black', command=do_music)



load_window1()
```

thanks for your answers

Comment: What `destroy_window1()` does is destroying `window1` (root window) and then create another *Toplevel* window. Since there is no root window, one will be created implicitly. So the final result is two windows created.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use the `widraw()` method which simply hides window1:

```
def destroy_window1():
    window1.withdraw()
    load_window2()
```

To read more on the `.withdraw()` method you can read the Tk documentation here: [https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/windows.html#:~:text=Iconifying%20and%20Withdrawing](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/windows.html#:%7E:text=Iconifying%20and%20Withdrawing)

Comment: What you say is incorrect, the *first root window is destroyed*.  It can be verified by adding `print(id(window1))` at the beginning of `destroy_window1()` and adding `print(id(window2.master))` at the end of `load_window2()`. They should show different values.

Comment: @acw1668 thanks for the correction. I guess I assumed something and didn't properly research it. I edited my answer to just show a possible solution

Comment: How do you destroy the hidden root window later based on OP code?

Comment: When a window has been hidden with the withdraw() method, you can still use window1.destroy as a command for a button or bind it to the X button being clicked on any other window. It still exists, just hidden.

Comment: I have said *"based on OP code"*. Actually the simple solution is to use `Tk()` instead of `Toplevel()` for `window2`.

Comment: Well, you edited the comment after I had a chance to answer and it didn't say "based on OP code" before. 
If you insist, if OP's intention is to not have window1 reappear after window2 has been shown, and window2 is the last window the user sees, he can add `window2.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", window1.destroy)` to the function `load_window2` and that will properly close the application and return `exit code 0` when the X button is clicked on window 2.

Comment: @acw1668 Sure that can be done, it's a great solution. But we can't know for sure OP does not wish to show window1 again. Using ` .withdraw` will give him the option to return from window1 to window2 without destroying window1 and having to recreate it.